# Launch a Jenkins build job from an other job

Tags: jenkins

I would want to launch a build of a Jenkins build job, without using plugins, but using a python script.
Is there a function to do that ?

Example :
I've a "job1" and a "job2".
In a script of job1, I want to write something like "start(job2)"...

Any suggestion ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512807/calling-a-jenkins-build-from-outside-of-jenkins ... good luck executing a python script without a plugin tho..  https://pythonhosted.org/python-jenkins/index.html#api-documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution : I needed to add a token to my job, and when I call my job, I use this url : "https://jenkins-server.srv/job/my-job/build?delay=0sec&token=my-token"

I've chosen the token here : (sorry for the french version)
[image]

Comment: @cooowThe Url which you have given is not working will give new one.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you don't want to use a plugin, which would make job configuration much more simple, but you could use the [Remote Access API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) to achieve this.

Comment: I don't want to use a plugin because I need to launch jobs according some conditions, that I can just test in python script.
Thanks for your answer, I'll read this documentation!