# Jenkins Manual Step by remote call

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins Build Pipeline plug-in for build pipelines. In mine pipeline I have manual step ( Build other project (Manual Step) ). When I trigger build it stops on this manual step (it's ok) and now I want to run it. But I don't want to trigger it via jenkins GUI but via call from some other application.

Example (Jenkins jobs pipeline):

Build -> Deploy Test -> (manual) Deploy Production

now I want second app with big button "Test ok, deploy on production" and via it call the jenkins manual job.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, have a look at this: it´s explaining how to use Jenkins´ Webservice API to call a Build from outside of jenkins:

[Calling a jenkins build from outside of jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512807/calling-a-jenkins-build-from-outside-of-jenkins)

Comment: yes, but this does not move Build Pipeline forward, just starts new build from this step. In this case information about upstream job which triggered this one is lost.