# Email trigger and reply email on Jenkins

Tags: email, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

There some way to trigger a build on Jenkins with e-mail and after the end of the job, the jenkins reply automatically this e-mail to the email sender?

Comment: Please take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512807/calling-a-jenkins-build-from-outside-of-jenkins/24535288#24535288

Comment: Maybe (Mail Commander Plugin)[https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mail+Commander+Plugin] might help you with job starting. Email-ext plugin can send a response email when the build finishes, Though I have no idea if you can link one email to another as reply.

Comment: @izzekil I already tryed the Mail Commander Plugin without sucess. I will try the email-ext plugin and see the results. Thanks

Comment: @kaserm I don't understand how the link you posted can help-me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve the problem using [Mail commander plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mail+Commander+Plugin)