# Is it possible to trigger a build from a mercurial repository without cloning it?

Tags: jenkins

I want my job to be triggered by changes to a mercurial repository (with an ssh address), but I don't want that job to try to clone that repository.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a [post-commit hook](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) that calls the [proper Jenkins API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512807/calling-a-jenkins-build-from-outside-of-jenkins).

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin that can help you with this, check it out here on Jenkins, https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FSTrigger+Plugin. I did achieve the same on Hudson a while ago.

Comment: This plugin only allows me to poll file or directory.

I need to poll a mercurial repository with an ssh address.