# 405 Error when attempting to trigger remote Jenkins job with wget

Tags: jenkins, wget, http-status-code-405

I've got a remote Jenkins job which does not require any login to start.  This is a parameterized job, so it is normally started with "Build With Parameters".

When trying to trigger this build (with default parameters), I call the following:

`wget [url_to_job]/build`

And I get this error:

```
Connecting to 10.57.112.238:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 405 Method Not Allowed
2016-03-14 11:49:34 ERROR 405: Method Not Allowed.
```

From what I have read, I would think that this should work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: For a parameterized job, use /buildWithParameters. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18823307/172599

Answer (score 2):

1. First, the URL for Remote Trigger should be wget [url_to_job]/buildWithParameters not [url_to_job]/build.
2. You can pass parameters by using wget [url_to_job]/buildWithParameters/?{parameterName}={parameterValue}
3. Eg : http://localhost:8080/jenkins/job/test/buildWithParameters/?name=arun

Comment: do remember the /buildWithParameters for parameterized job

Answer (score 1):

You better use curl instead of wget and also provide credentials for the command:

```
curl -XPOST --silent --show-error --user <user>:<key> <url_to_job>/build
```

Comment: OP says there's no login required. Why would curl be better than wget?

Comment: POST is the issue indeed

Answer (score 0):

wget --auth-no-challenge --delete-after --verbose "http://10.157.163.249:8080/job/scanning/buildWithParameters?token=scan&buildURL='abcdefg'"

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely is that you haven't copied the token over into the "Authentication Token" field of the build trigger. Clicking the checkbox isn't enough - Jenkins will silently remove the checkbox unless a token was provided.

Once I did this the following command worked:

```
wget --auth-no-challenge --user STRING --password STRING --output-document - 'http://localhost:8080/job/PROJECT/build?token=TOKEN'
```

Of course it is BAD PRACTICE to put passwords into scripts or the command line history. See [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/267470/wget-is-there-a-way-to-pass-username-and-password-from-a-file) to learn how to store the credentials in *~/.netrc*.