# Publish finished build to another Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build-process

I'm using two Jenkins servers of the same version with the same plugins on two machines. Let's call one of them *public* Jenkins and the other *private* Jenkins. I want to start a build A on the private server and afterwards start a build B on the public server.

I tried to solve this with the [Build Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Publisher+Plugin). I configured the private server by entering the server URL and credentials of the public. I set that build A should be published to the public server.

This works, the build job A is visible afterwards on the public server. I configured that Build job B should be triggered when the published job A is done, but this doesn't work. Build A is visible on the public server, but although the build process was successful on private machine, there are no information about last build date and status.

Is there anything that I missed? Is it really possible to trigger a build job after a subscribed build job has finished or is there a easier way?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Build Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Publisher+Plugin) reads:

> [...] *then send the results to another Jenkins which is facing the outside world.*
>
> [...] *build records from private Jenkins is sent to public Jenkins, through HTTP.*

I interpret this as the results being published just for being viewed on the public server.

Just like a book publisher: He or she doesn't write books or continuations of books. He or she just publishes them for reading.

See [Calling a jenkins build from outside of jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512807/calling-a-jenkins-build-from-outside-of-jenkins) for how to trigger a build on a Jenkins server from remote, i.e. from your *private* on your *public*.

Comment: thank you for clarifying my confusion about this plugin. remote access api is exactly what I was looking for. http:// some server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&PARAMETER=Value