# Jenkins REST API Auth using URL parameters

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying configure my Jenkins to allow remote job trigger using REST API. If I pass username and password using basic authentication header param, I'm able to trigger the job

```
-u <username>:<api token> http://localhost:8080/job/kp-push-example/build
```

However if I pass username and api token in url, Jenkins is unable to authenticate, it uses anonymous user and throws error, as anonymous user does not have prevailage to execute the job.

```
http://<username>:<apitoken>@localhost:8080/job/kp-push-example/build
```

Below is the error message.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2Fjob%2Fkp-push-example%2Fbuild'/>
        <script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2Fjob%2Fkp-push-example%2Fbuild');</script>
    </head>
    <body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required

        <!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
-->


    </body>
</html>
```

How to configure Jenkins to allow url basic auth?
Jenkins version: 2.129

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a Jenkins build from outside of Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512807/calling-a-jenkins-build-from-outside-of-jenkins)

Answer (score 2):

Could you please share in which user your are actually using and if it has a valid token?
Also how are you triggering it? Are you using a script, call it with some Server-Logic, ...?

Here's a tested and working example for cURL:

```
curl -s -XPOST 'http://localhost:8080/job/kp-push-example/build?token=TOKEN' -u "admin:0000ADMIN-TOKEN00000"
```