# How to trigger set of Python Test Automation( Selenium script) from Web application

Tags: python, selenium, web-applications, web-deployment, browser-automation

I have got a complex requirement for Test Automation,

About my project: It'an internal Python web application where we have multiple environments like Test/UAT/Prod/Pre-Prod. I have created my set of Test Automation scripts which execute as a separate project. It's up and running.

The new requirement says: I want to give the ability for the developers to run my Test automation scripts from the web application - say like in Homepage->Menu - I need to add a button as 'Automation Login', When a user/developer click this button a new web page should open, in that page I should display a button say 'Trigger Automation' to execute my selenium script and run also I should display the pass and fail with log details in the web page itself.  *Is this possible to achieve? Can selenium run from a webpage trigger?*

*In short, we want to see the selenium test automation result on the fly in the web application page, is it doable?*

I'm not a much experience person in the development world, let me know if any links or ideas how to start this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any off the shelf solution available. A closer approach would be as below,

1. Integrate Allure reporting to Test Automation Framework if not present currently.
2. Create a jenkins free style project to trigger the test Automation Framework.
3. On click of the "trigger Automation Button" invoke jenkins API to trigger the configured jenkins job which will kick start the automation script run. [Calling a Jenkins build from outside of Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512807/calling-a-jenkins-build-from-outside-of-jenkins).
4. Allure reports are dumped to WORKSPACE/allure_report directory on the slave on completion of job execution. A standard URL can be provided to access the allure dashboard which can accessed by developers to verify the Automation execution results.

Comment: Thanks @VNsCorner , Will explain the possibility to Team now