# How to trigger Jenkin Jobs from Microsoft Team Channel?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, microsoft-teams

I am looking to trigger Jenkins's job from the Microsoft team's channel. Can anyone provide step by step implementation of this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two nice options you can use:

- [Outgoing Webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook?tabs=urljsonpayload%2Cdotnet) - Will scan for words in the chats and send a notification to your Jenkins server.
- [Commander](https://nimbella.com/blog/commander-for-microsoft-teams-your-custom-bot-that-runs-on-your-command) - Second and more customizable option is using the Commander add on for teams, which in addition to builtin commands provides the ability to [Create your own Custom Commands](https://nimbella.com/blog/commander-for-microsoft-teams-your-custom-bot-that-runs-on-your-command#how-to-create-and-edit-your-custom-commands).

With both options you will be able to tigger Jenkins jobs via the [Remote Access API](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api/), see the [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512807/calling-a-jenkins-build-from-outside-of-jenkins/8512956#8512956) for additional info on remote execution.

Comment: @QualityMatters - Does the help provided by Noam resolves your issue?

Comment: Nope. This information is already in multiple places, and before posting questions here, I have visited all these links. What I am looking for implementation, Not just references.

Comment: Solution provided by @Noam Helmer should work. Could you please share more details on things you have tried and specific issues?