# Jenkins pipeline schedule for certain branch

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkinsfile that looks like that:

```
pipeline {
    agent { node { label 'docker' } }
    triggers { cron('0 0 12 ? * TUE *') }
    environment{
        VAR1 ='VAL1'
    }
    stages {
        stage('build'){
            steps{
                script {
                    cleanWs()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to build on cron only `main` branch and not build any other branches, e.g. `feature/..`

Please advise how it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

based on my experience, you can select the branch to generate webhook on Gitlab. But if you are using Github, there's nothing to set the branch you want to generate webhook.
So if you are using github, You should build a Server to perform like a webhook filter.

Here's the flow.

1. If push event uccurs in your repository, and you set the endpoint to your own server.
   Your server will receive webhook payload.
2. In the webhook payload data, there's information that tells you where this event happend from. (like `feature/**` branch or `main` branch) in the payload data, there's `ref` field that tells you where this push event happend from. (https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads)
3. If the event happened from desired branch(in your case main branch), then you trigger the pipeline by sending http request from your server to your jenkins server.
4. you can trigger pipeline jobs using your own server by sending request to your jenkins remote API. see this link for detail([Calling a Jenkins build from outside of Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512807/calling-a-jenkins-build-from-outside-of-jenkins))

but you have to publish API token from your jenkins setting before trigger jenkins job using remote API.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0zj6ni89B7c

watch this video can hep you understand triggering jenkins job